# Create data syncs using two tables

Tags: apache-spark, etl, palantir-foundry, data-ingestion, incremental-build

I want to create a data syncs in Palantir using un update (update + insert) transaction on three fields from two diffent tables, there is anoption in Palantir syncs to use twin table but i can't see how to add three fields in the incremental field from two different tables.

Do you have any idea how to do this in Palantir?